# how to update just the year in Teradata Date Column

Tags: teradata

I have a Teradata table with delivery dates:-

```
Delivery_Date
24-03-2018 07:34:00.000000
29-03-2018 07:34:00.000000
30-03-2018 07:34:00.000000
```

I just want to update the YEAR (from 2018 to 2019) in the Delivery_Date

```
Delivery_Date
24-03-2019 07:34:00.000000
29-03-2019 07:34:00.000000
30-03-2019 07:34:00.000000
```

DateAdd - i think works in SQL Server. Is there any function in Teradata for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer after some R and D

```
update tablename set delivery_date = delivery_date + interval '1' year
```

Comment: With INTERVAL '1' YEAR, you can have issues with February 29. It's generally better to use something like `add_months(delivery_date,12)`.